# Handle selectbox update in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

uiModel.appreciation is a key / value object:

```
{ "key": "B", "value": "Better"}
```

In my Directive:

```
scope.appreciationsArray = [{key: 'A', value: 'Good'}, {key: 'B', value: 'Better'}, {key: 'C', value: 'Best'}];
```

Directive template:

```
<select name="type" ng-change="onChangeAppreciationSelectBox($index)" class="form-control" ng-disabled="disabled" required ng-model="uiModel.appreciation.key" data-ng-options="appreciationObj.key as appreciationObj.value for appreciationObj in appreciationsList">
                </select>
```

This renders a nice select box and sets the selected item to B / Better.
When changing to another item I want the uiModel.appreciation object to be updated accordingly. So far only the key is updated, the value propertyhowever keeps its initial value.

Looking for the correct Angular way to do it, must be possible without the use of custom Javascript right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the appreciation as the model and as the selector in the **[comprehension expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)** instead of the key property:

```
<select
    ng-model="uiModel.appreciation" 
    ng-options="appreciation.value for appreciation in appreciations">
```

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.uiModel = {
    appreciation: {
      "key": "B",
      "value": "Better"
    }
  }

  $scope.appreciations = [{
    key: 'A',
    value: 'Good'
  }, {
    key: 'B',
    value: 'Better'
  }, {
    key: 'C',
    value: 'Best'
  }];

  $scope.uiModel = {
    appreciation: $scope.appreciations[0]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
<p>Selected appreciation: {{uiModel.appreciation | json}}</p>
<select
    ng-model="uiModel.appreciation" 
    ng-options="appreciation.value for appreciation in appreciations">
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: this solves my issue for the most of it, however the initial selected item in the select box isnt set. In your code snippet, at the end you write:   $scope.uiModel = { appreciation: $scope.appreciations[0] } >>> the appreciation property on the uiModel is already set, so I dont need / want to declare it again. The default selected item on the select box isnt set however. Why is that?

Comment: The uiModel.appreciation in your example is set to an object literal and not one in the list. It's a completely different object that happens to have the same values as one in the list.